# How can I get time difference between 2 SQL columns and ignore date and return as HH:mm?

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm trying to get the time difference in HH:mm format for 2 different columns and ignore the date and calculate just the times.

This is what I came up with but the result is in decimal format, I would like it to be formatted as HH:mm

```
SELECT TimeEnd, 
       TimeStart, 
       ABS(ROUND(DATEDIFF(MI,CONVERT(TIME,TimeEnd),CONVERT(TIME,TimeStart))/60.0,2))
```

Comment: Do you still want to ignore dates if they're different between the two columns?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: So a start time of 11pm (2300 hours) day1 and EndTime of 1am (0100 hours) day2 should be 22 hours??? This seems like it would be 2 hours to me.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  This is just the request that i'm fulfilling. :)

Comment: OK. Well you don't want to use division here, you want to use modulo. Honestly the whole ignoring dates makes this absurd.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request well - you are looking for such code:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (d1 DATETIME, d2 DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @T ( d1 , d2 )
VALUES ( '20171023 23:00:10', '20171021 11:00:10' )

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), d1-d2, 108), 5)
FROM @T
```